# aframe physics - Collision between static bodies

Tags: physics, aframe, cannon.js

I am using [aframe physics extra component](https://github.com/wmurphyrd/aframe-physics-extras) and trying to detect collision between two static bodies.

Here is my codepen - https://codepen.io/nirajupadhyay11/pen/gQraNq

However, I am not sure, why it is not working.

Here is the code -

```
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component@^4.1.2/dist/aframe-animation-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/v3.1.2/dist/aframe-physics-system.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-physics-extras@0.1.2/dist/aframe-physics-extras.min.js"></script>

<a-scene physics="gravity: 0">

<a-entity id='ball' position="0 1 -3" material="color:green;" geometry="primitive:sphere; radius: 1;" static-body physics-collider="ignoreSleep: true"  animation="property: position; dur: 1500; easing: linear; to: 5 1 -3; dir:alternate; easing: easeInSine; loop:true">
</a-entity>

<a-plane color='grey' static-body rotation="-90 0 0" width="100" height="100"></a-plane>

<a-entity id='ball2' position="3 1 -3" material="color:red;" geometry="primitive:sphere; radius: 1;" static-body physics-collider="ignoreSleep: true"></a-entity>

</a-scene>
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working. The `physics-collider` provides an event `collisions` which is emitted when both static bodies collide with each other.

If you add an event listener

```
// var obj = one of the static bodies
obj.addEventListener("collisions", (e)=>{
  // collision!
})
```

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr6vuq20/1/).

---

If you expect an actual collision where one of the spheres fly away, then set

```
physics-collider="ignoreSleep: false"
```

The `ignoreSleep` attribute is a flag responsible for waking up sleeping bodies ([docs](https://github.com/wmurphyrd/aframe-physics-extras))

Comment: Thanks Adam. Is there a way to know the ids of both of the static bodies colliding? I looked at the value of e from the event listener but could not find that. Only the id of the static-body that has physics-collider="ignoreSleep: true" associated was available in the event log (e)

Comment: The collision event contains an array of the bodies you're colliding with. `event.detail.els[0].id` should worki for the first one